# Migration from ol2 to ol6 fixed strategy missing

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I try to migrate from ol2 to ol6.

My ol2 uses OpenLayers.Strategy abstract class with Fixed() and BBOX members:

```
var strategy = layerData.Strategy == "fixed" ? new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed() : new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX();
```

In ol6 docs discribed this module ol/loadingstrategy and from this module can be imported **all**, **bbox** and **tile** strategies. But I din't see **fixed** 
strategy in OL6 module.

Any idea why this module ol/loadingstrategy dosen't contains fixed modul?

Comment: **all** and **fixed** both make a single request, so they should be equivalent